# issues with undefined(inputenc)

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

I have problem with code - `\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in my class, i am sure, that this file is fully written in utf8, i tried to convert in multiple way, so it must be in utf8. But still same error. Any tip ? My class - http://pastebin.com/tVRpyZCF
and error message -

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

I tried to run in with MikTex and in TexLive too but same error. I checked Texmaker enconding, but there is UTF-8 set too..

Comment: I found solution, u just need to set `\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}` at the bottom of all require packages...

Comment: It's a clear bug in `pdfx.sty`, which says `\ifcat^^c0\active` where it should of course be `\ifcat\noexpand^^c0\active`, because if `^^c0` is active to begin with, it will be expanded.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bug in `pdfx.sty`: at line 1398 (where the error message points to) we find

```
\ifcat^^c0\active \pdf@activecharstrue\fi
```

Now, when `inputenc` is loaded with the `utf8` encoding, the character `^^c0` *is* made active. But `\ifcat` needs to find two unexpandable tokens to which apply the test, so it *expands* the active character and the error happens.

The line should be

```
\ifcat\noexpand^^c0\noexpand~\pdf@activecharstrue\fi
```

so comparing the character token `^^c0` with a character token which indeed has category code 13.

It's a misunderstanding of what `\ifcat` does: the current test will *always* give a wrong result, because `\active` is a control sequence which is not let to a character, so it's considered to have category code 16.

Moving `\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}` past `\RequirePackage{pdfx}` will solve your particular issue, but of course the test done by `pdfx.sty` is completely useless.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and explanation :) !!